# LIC adjustment in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, convolution, spline

I have to do some line [integral convolution visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral_convolution) in Octave. The [matlab package](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16201-toolbox-image?focused=5133182&tab=function) works pretty nice so far. There is only one issue: you can't specify the input pattern. I do not care for making the bouquet of flowers LIC blurred or so, but I would like the output to be significantly bigger than the input vector field (e.g. making 640x480 LIC image from 64x48 vector field).

**Is splining of the input vector field the only option?**

Comment: "Bouquet of flowers"? Eh? Care to give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help understand what you're after exactly? Your question is pretty vague otherwise. Though yes, it's hard to imagine how you'd use a vector field that doesn't match the image size in terms of an underlying grid, so you probably _do_ have to interpolate it onto the image grid one way or another (presumably by 'splining' you mean performing cubic spline interpolation, right?)